# How to perform some operations on text files using Python Only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains data like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RwSrIKD_GUZuToP7bRg8fPoG-4ABSLCS/view?usp=sharing. It is just a small example, but the real one is pretty similar. How can I calculate total sales?

I am unable to perform operations on text files.

I want to calculate total sale without using any library like pandas and numpy. I want to calculate it using python only.
I am able to read and write and append to it in the text files but how will i perform some calculations that thing I am not getting.

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: **What code have you tried**?  Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CalebGoodman I am unable to perform operations on the text file, I only know that how to read, write and append texts from the file but here we need to calculate something there I am stuck.

Comment: @KlausD. I am able to read the data from text files only but how to perform calculation on the text files there i am getting stuck

Comment: So, you have made no serious attempt to solve the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through python, without using special library e.g pandas or numpy.
Use file handling operations and data structures to handle data.

considering your Input file, suppose your data:

```
Date,SKU,Unit Price,Quantity,Total Price
2019-10-11,name of product1,5,2,10
2019-10-11,name of product2,3,4,12
```

see below example, for handling.

```
sale = 0  # take a sale variable
with open('test.txt', 'r') as stream:
    data = stream.readlines()  # get the file content as list
    for item in data[1:]:  # iterate over list from second line
        sale = sale + int(item.split(',')[-1])  # add data from total column
print("Total sale:", sale)
```

Output:

```
Total sale: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you provided as an example seems to be a CSV file. Python provides a csv library to handle these (csv). Below is an example of how to traverse through rows and calculate sum of a specific column in the csv file. Modify it as per your needs and you will be good to go.

> You can read more about the csv library here:-
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
`
import csv
filename = 'yourfilename.extension'
total_sales = 0.00
total_rows = 0

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    headers = next(csvreader)

    salesHeaderIndex = 4 # from the example the index of Total Price Column


    for row in csvreader:
        total_sales += float(row[salesHeaderIndex])
        total_rows += 1

    print("Total ", total_sales, total_rows)`
```

Comment: This is giving a correct output thanks for this